# Test with Rspec using session sinatra

Tags: rspec, sinatra

I have sinatra appliction using session, how do I test a page that uses session?

I using Rspec + sinatra

Tks

Comment: I think you should use Rack::Test (or something on top of that like Capybara) to test session aware code

Answer (score 1):

[This page](http://blog.ianmiller.nyc/2014/09/29/working-with-rack-sessions/), show's the main problem of testing session with `rspec` and `sinatra`.

The main problem is that the variable `session` is not accessible from the test code. To solve it, it suggests (and I confirm) to add the fowling lines at `spec/spec_helper.rb`:

```
def session
  last_request.env['rack.session']
end
```

It will make accessible a mocked session object from the last request at the test code.

Here's my controller code that read's a `code` param and stores its value at `session`:

```
post '/step2callback' do
  session['code'] = params['code']
end
```

Then here's test code:

```
context "making an authentication" do
  before do
    post "/step2callback", code: "code_sample"
  end
  it "reads the param code and saves it at session" do
    expect(session['code']).to eq("code_sample")
  end  
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Same like all other pages.

You need to clarify your question. What is problem with testing session. If problems is that user need to be logged in, then you can use something like this in spec file:

```
before :each do
  post "/login", {:username => "myuser", :password => "mypass"}
end
```

which will log you in before each test.

Answer (score 0):

I was only able to get it to work by disabling sessions for the test environment. This blog post has a good example: http://benprew.posterous.com/testing-sessions-with-sinatra

Comment: Internet archive link:
https://web.archive.org/web/20130418214800/http://benprew.posterous.com/testing-sessions-with-sinatra