# Rspec test if a session variable was set in a controller action

Tags: session, testing, rspec

I have an rspec test that posts to an action.  In the action, a session variable is definitely set, however in my controller test, the session hash is empty.  How do I check in an Rspec test to see if the controller set the session variable to the right value?

Comment: So what was the actual cause of this? (since you ticked an answer but didn't really explain)

Comment: The answer was correct for the question I asked, but my problem ended up being un-related to my question

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can access session directly in rspec like this: `session[:key]`. Just compare that with the value you want.

Comment: sorry i guess i should have said what ive tried.  i tried that, but the session was empty.  the spec has an empty session but using the controller the normal way, it works

Comment: @Chris, I've done that for many times so I know it works. Please paste the code if necessary.

Answer (score 4):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434800/test-with-rspec-using-session-sinatra/34634272#34634272). The main problem is that the variable `session` is not accessible from the test code. To solve it, add the fowling lines at `spec/spec_helper.rb`:

```
def session
  last_request.env['rack.session']
end
```

Comment: this was probably the answer to what was actually wrong at the time I posted this.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use any `before_filter` in your controller? This could be the case, if `before_filter` changes the flow, and your code with assigning a variable to the session has not even evaluated.

For example you may have this line in your controller:

```
# ...
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
# ...
```

That means if you are not signed in, you will never enter any method in this controller. So the `session` variable will be empty.